# Prevent resize of content in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have created a data template for a data class. The width of the grid created by the datatemplate is bound to a property in the data class, ie, the size of the control matters.

I am creating a list of the data class objects, and adding them to an items control in MainWindow.

**Update:**

I would like to line up the controls from the data list one after another, and not have them resize.

Example:

[---------box1----------][--box2--][------box3-----]

each are the same data template type, and different widths. Perhaps I shouldn't be using itemsControl, but I am unsure of what other control to use to achieve this.

Any help would be much appreciated. I can post XAML

Comment: Could you please include sample data template. Is your box1 width is predefined or it should adjust itself according to the length of the record while initially loading it?

Answer (score 1):

Can you post some XAML.
It can depend on the HorizontalContentAlignment of the ItemsControl or the style of your ItemContainer/ItemPanel.